# Cordova apps Input fields cannot be selected on iOS 9

Tags: ios, cordova, input, keyboard

I have started facing this issue today after upgrading to iOS 9. My app has a login page at the start and the input fields have stopped responding completely. When i tap on the input fields the keyboard comes up, but then nothing gets reflected when i type something. Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: We need some code to see if something seems wrong.
One time, I faced this issue while a `user-select: none` was applied to the parent `div` of the input.

Comment: Not a problem with code as this was working perfectly in iOS 8. I have not made any changes, but now if I type something then only 1 character comes up and then the input field stops responding. Will put in the code in some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an **ID** to the `<input>` field and add `-webkit-user-select: auto;` to the **ID**. This will fix your problems.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using an id on each field, you can use this css that will apply to all the inputs with type text

```
input[type=text]{
   -webkit-user-select: auto;
}
```

Comment: originally i was using :  
`*:not (input, textarea) {  
    -webkit-user-select : none;  
}`  
  
But this actually broke it in the current version. I think now everything is marked as `user-select : none` by default. So changing the css to the below worked :  
  
`input, textarea {  
-webkit-user-select: auto;  
}`

Answer (score 1):

2020 Update - To make the cursor behave well with click focus events and native virtual keyboards on iOS13 and Cordova(iOS) 5.0.1, stop using the default UIWebView and start using WKWebview. This may cause a whole lot of side issues in your existing app, however, UIWebView has been deprecated since iOS8... its time to move on.

This Ionic WKWebView Plugin fixed this issue with React Material-UI:
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

To install it run this command in your console from inside your Cordova project folder:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```